# Why my Django exception middleware does not log stack trace

Tags: django

I am trying to set up a custom exception handler.

```
# settings.py
LOGGING = {
        // ...
        'handlers': {
            'mail_admins': {
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            },

        },
        'loggers': {
            'django': {
                'handlers': ['applogfile', 'mail_admins'],
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'propagate': True,
            }
            
        }
    }
```

When I use the Django default exception handler and there is a Django error, I get an email containing the debug page, including the stack trace.   However, I want to have my own exception middleware, so I added the following:

```
# middleware.py
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
class MyExceptionMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):

        return render(request, template_name='error_message.html', context={
                'title':'Error',
                'message':'Sorry, we encountered an unexpected error'
            })
```

```
# settings.py

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # other middlewares
     ...

    'middleware.MyExceptionMiddleware',
]
```

After I added this, the debug email that I get is missing the stack trace.  It tells me that there is an "Internal server error" at the url, but it doesn't give any details of the errors.

I know I can override error handlers (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) which would give me the full stack trace, but I am wondering why when I use a middleware to catch exceptions I don't get the stack trace.

Comment: i have one question where you put your middleware as far as i know if you put middleware anywhere you have to put you middleware file like this appname.middleware.MyExceptionMiddleware so where you put that file so you can directly access the middleware.py

Comment: The path to the middleware in the above is simplified, but django does render my custom exception template so I don't think it's an issue.

Comment: i dont have the answer but it raise question to me where have you put that middleware file can you please tell me i think you have put your middleware file besides manage.py file if i am right?

Comment: I put it in utility/middleware.py